# RSA Padding with Bouncy Castle on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, encryption, java-me, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm using Bouncy Castle to encrypt strings to send them to my java web service where they are decrypted, when the message reaches the server I get a `BadPaddingException`, anybody know how to properly add the padding to an RSA Cipher with Bouncy Castle on J2ME?

This is the encryption code on the client:

```
public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
  {
     RSAKeyParameters publicKey = new RSAKeyParameters(false, new BigInteger(_publicKeyModulus), new BigInteger(_publicKeyExponent));
     RSAEngine engine = new RSAEngine();
     engine.init(true, publicKey);

     byte[] output = engine.processBlock(data, 0, data.length);

     return output;
  }
```

And this is how I decrypt it server side:

```
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
            return cipherData;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EncryptorDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EncryptorDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EncryptorDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EncryptorDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EncryptorDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `RSAEngine` directly use the [`PKCS1Encoding`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/encodings/PKCS1Encoding.html) class and construct it with

```
PKCS1Encoding engine = new PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());
```